# Need to set the volume of the <audio> to zero or just want to mute it for the mobile android chrome and for safari for ios

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I want to set the audio tag volume to zero or want to make it as a mute using `jQuery`. The muted property is working for desktop chrome but when I try this in android chrome version, it does not work. My code is as follow :

```
song = document.getElementById('audio');
song.volume = 0.0;
```

I also tried

```
song.muted = true;
```

but nothing is working for mobile android and ios.
Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices, particularly Apple ones, dont let you set the volume on elements. The idea is that the volume controls for the device should control the volume of items.